# How to calculate remaining minutes to "next" half an hour or hour?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I would like to calculate the remaining minutes to the "next" half an hour or hour.

Say i get a start time string of `07:15`, i want it to calculate the remaining minutes to the nearest half an hour `(07:30)`.

```
That would be 15min.
```

Then i can also have an instance where the start time can be `07:45` and i want it to calculate the remaining minutes to the nearest hour `(08:00)`.

```
That would also be 15min.
```

So any string less then 30min in a hour would calculate to the nearest half an hour `(..:30)` and any string over 30min would calculate to the nearest hour `(..:00)`.

I don't want to do a bunch of if statements, because i get from time strings that can start from and minute in an hour.

This is what i do not want to do:

```
if (int.Parse(fromTimeString.Right(2)) < 30)
{
    //Do Calculation
}
else
{
    //Do Calculation
}

public static string Right(this String stringValue, int noOfCharacters)
{
    string result = null;

    if (stringValue.Length >= noOfCharacters)
    {
        result = stringValue.Substring(stringValue.Length - noOfCharacters,       noOfCharacters);
    }
    else
    {
        result = "";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Is there not an easier way with `linq` or with the `DateTime` class

Comment: Do you really mean "nearest", or do you actually mean "next"? In most of your examples you seem to be calculating the amount of remaining time until the *next* half-hour. This is not necessarily the nearest one, as that could be at an earlier time.

Comment: @MarkByers Sorry, i mean "next".

Comment: If the input is "08:30" should the output be "30" or "0"?

Comment: @MarkByers It will be 30 and the same for 08:00. The output will be 30 as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use modulo operator `%` with 30. Your result will be equal to `(60 - currentMinutes) % 30`. About `LINQ` its used for collections so i can't realy see how it can be used in your case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var minutesToNextHalfHour = (60 - yourDateTimeVariable.Minutes) % 30;
```

Comment: This will return 30 when `Minutes = 0` or `Minutes = 30`.

Comment: If seconds are considered, it is incorrect for hour boundary. e.g. For 11:00:25, this will return 11:00:00 rather than 11:30:00.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `DateTime` tick-round approach to get the timespan until next half hour:

```
var minutes = 30;
var now = DateTime.Now;
var ticksMin = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes).Ticks;
DateTime rounded = new DateTime(((now.Ticks + (ticksMin/2)) / ticksMin) * ticksMin);
var diff=rounded-now;
var minUntilNext = diff.TotalMinutes > 0 ? diff.TotalMinutes : minutes + diff.TotalMinutes;
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
int remainingMinutes = (current.Minute >= 30)
    ? 60 - current.Minute
    : 30 - current.Minute;
```

Comment: For 8:00 result will be 30 and for 8:30 it will be 0. You might want to use `>=`

Answer (score 1):

```
var hhmm = fromTimeString.Split(':');
var mins = int.Parse(hhmm[1]);
var remainingMins = (60 - mins) % 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "7:16";
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "h:mm", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
var minutesPastHalfHour = datetime.Minute % 30;
var minutesBeforeHalfHour = 30 - minutesPastHalfHour;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use modulo + `TimeSpan.TryParse`:

```
public static int ComputeTime(string time)
{
    TimeSpan ts;

    if (TimeSpan.TryParse(time, out ts))
    {
        return (60 - ts.Minutes) % 30;
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Time is not valid", "time");
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test1 = "7:27";
    string test2 = "7:42";

    Console.WriteLine(ComputeTime(test1));
    Console.WriteLine(ComputeTime(test2));

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```